# What's wrong with my solution to this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Given the following integral:

> $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{6}}dx$

My solution is as follows:

$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^\frac{5}{6}}dx = \int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{5}{6}}dx$

$\int_1^\infty x^{-\frac{5}{6}}dx = -5x^{-\frac{1}{5}}|^\infty_1$

$\to \lim_{b \to \infty} -5b^{-\frac{1}{5}} -5$

$= -5$

Apparently, somewhere I've erred in my solution...

Comment: You should be subtracting $-5$, which is why the correct solution isn’t negative.

Comment: @paulinho, your observation is correct and astute (if the integral converges, the answer must be postive), but the main error occurs in the preceding line. See my answer.

Comment: @BarryCipra Ah yes that’s correct, didn’t catch that.

Answer (score 3):

The main error is in the (tacit) indefinite integration:

$$\int x^{-5/6}\,dx\not=-5x^{-1/5}+C$$

It should be

$$\int x^{-5/6}\,dx=6x^{1/6}+C$$

which you can check by differentiating, noting that $-{5\over6}={1\over6}-1$, not $-{1\over5}-1$.